# UCWA and Skype Web SDK not working?

Tags: javascript, https, skype, skype-for-business, ucwa

How to get authorization through the Skype Web SDK (UCWA) on the basis of official examples?

I have a purchased account to use Skype for Business and entrance to the admin panel of Office 365. There were examples Download the official Skype Web SDK and [UCWA](https://ucwa.skype.com/code) samples, which are deployed on the local machine (Apache server with directory localhost). I used to enter the account art@shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com that I created when buying Skype for Business. As a result, I get a response in the form of pop-up messages `Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin`

At the request header to `https://lyncdiscover.shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com/xframe` is an attribute `X-Ms-Origin: http://localhost`, can this problem? Long enough debugging process led me to the idea to connect the frame by hand and communicate with him through the post message, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your application domain should be added to Skype Servers' whitelist. Or you can filter X-Ms-Origin by using some proxies or browser plugin (I've used [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-headers-for-google/innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi))
2. [UCWA is currently available only to customers who have Skype for Business on-premises.](https://ucwa.skype.com/about-ucwa) So you won't be able to login to Office365 account.